# Count changes of a value over time?

Tags: mysql, time, count, distinct

again I am stuck with counting something in MySQL. The database structure is far from SOers´d call optimal, but nevertheless I do not have an influence here and have to live with it. Probably that´s one of the reasons why I need help again to get some information out of it :)

Assume I have:
some_id (not the PK of the table, not unique),
year, month (no date fields just two integer fields),
some_flag (character that is either A or B) .

Now I´d like to know how often some_flag has changed (in a given time span). The time span is not utterly important in the first approach, I just need to know how many changes happened. Note that changes can only happen monthly. My query:

```
 SELECT  some_id,year,some_flag FROM mytable
 WHERE some_flag = "A" OR someflag = "B"
 AND year > 2005
 GROUP BY some_id,some_flag
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT some_flag) > 1
```

returns an empty result set. What´s wrong with it? I am sure there are years in which the flag changes over months...

Isn't something like

```
 select .... , sum(case when month=month-1 and some_flag != some_flag then 1 else 0 end)     as changecount
```

possible ?

Comment: Can you post some example data and what output you would like please?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT some_flag, COUNT(some_id) FROM mytable
WHERE some_flag = "A" OR someflag = "B"
AND year > 2005
GROUP BY some_flag
HAVING COUNT(some_id) > 1
```

**-Edit-**
If you want to see a month over month count, try this:
(Note: it will only show months where it has changed)

```
SELECT some_flag, year, month, COUNT(some_id) FROM mytable
WHERE some_flag = "A" OR someflag = "B"
AND year > 2005
GROUP BY some_flag, month, year
HAVING COUNT(some_id) > 1
```

Comment: This is close... but unfortunately it just returns the total amount of ids, not only the #number of changes. This would only work if there was only one observation at one point in time (some_id) in the set. Probably, I´d better look to post this question scripting related.

Comment: Is there a column with the number of changes made as well? Your question doesn't indicate that.

Comment: If there is a column with number of changes, you can replace `COUNT(some_id)` with `SUM(num_changes)`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you need to do this in two parts.

First, execute this SQL query to get all of the values for `some_id, some_flag`:

```
SELECT some_id, some_flag, year, month
FROM ...
WHERE year > 2005
ORDER BY some_id, some_flag, year, month
```

Then, run the output through a match / merge process to detect when `some_flag` changes for a given `some_id`.  Save the year and month that `some_flag` changes for reporting in the match / merge process.

Comment: Yup, this is what I try to set up currently and basically the reason why am trying my luck with another language right now...

Answer (score 0):

When grouping by `some_flag` you're making `COUNT(DISTINCT some_flag)` to be always 1.

Try gouping only by `some_id`. I hope this helps.